# NSLayoutConstraint for label inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have a tableViewCell with a label inside. Lets say I dont want to create an IBOutlet in this case. I want to add a constraint to the label based on a condition so that label moves 10pixels down if the condition is true. To be more precise, I want to achieve the constraint in the image below by code.

[image]

I have tried

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:amountLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   multiplier:1.0 constant:+10];
[amountLabel addConstraint:myConstraint];
```

but to no effect. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: `Superview.Top` should mean `amountLabel.superview`, not `cell.superview`.

Comment: Have you called setNeedUpdateConstraints and updateConstraintsIfNeeded?

Comment: When dealing with auto layout constraints in code, there exist several categories on `UIView` that ease the work for you. I use [FLKAutoLayout](https://github.com/dkduck/FLKAutoLayout), which I find very handy.

Comment: @Wain I tried with cell.superView as well. It doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to add that constraint to the superview to get it to work (always add constraints to the topmost view, or to the nearest common ancestor view).

I've found that working with constraints in code is WAY easier using a category library. My favorite is the one made by Richard Turton: https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

I think you will find adding constraints is much more intuitive using this.

**Example**

```
[amountLabel pinEdge:NSLayoutAttributeTop toEdge:NSLayoutAttributeTop ofView:superView inset:10];
```

Comment: Sure, added to the answer. If you ask me, the semantics are much more intuitive than using the Apple API.

Comment: In your specific case, you could also use the -(NSArray*)pinToSuperviewEdges:(JRTViewPinEdges)edges inset:(CGFloat)inset;  method, since you are working with amountLabel's superview

Comment: Seriously, The category made by @jrturton has made autolayout so much easier for me, that if he lived close to me I would have bought him a beer or given him a hug (based on his preference, of course).     Or maybe both :-D

Comment: Enough beers, and I'll hug anyone.